# Webpack - getting strong warning, how to fix it?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have created my own webpack angular. while i do build I am getting following error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
6541:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/esm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 ./src/main.ts
```

how to fix this?

Comment: I am curious - why have you created your own webpack environment? Angular/CLI is pretty nice.

Comment: I just require very simple single page, why do I require CLI?

Comment: the cli is a useful tool to use for creating angular/webpack apps

Comment: CLI is perfect for your purposes. https://cli.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a common problem that is fixed in a more recent version. According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898), make it stop showing up with the following:

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
  /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/,
  path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
),
```